# How to disable windows aunthentication pop up in port 80?

Tags: php, asp.net, database, windows, ftp

My website been having this issues this past few weeks. I have this authentication pop-up in browsers asking for username and password in port 80? and when I enter my FTP details it's goes through. What steps I should take to lift this off permanently?

It's running on asp.net and php. I have filezilla opened as is.

```
Athentication in http://example.net:80
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows 7, try to open IIS Manager, select your website, navigate to .Net Authorization, and check if all users are allowed.